# can some one explain how this function works?

Tags: c++

I cannot understand how this function (c++) works and how it return true or false?
The problem is with the (void)projection; I cannot understand that.

```
bool Node::SetupCamera(glm::mat4& projection, glm::mat4& modelview) {   
    (void)projection;
    (void)modelview;
    return false;
}
```

Edit:
Link to the code at github [link](https://github.com/gligneul/Scene-Graph/blob/master/Node.cpp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a stub; it does nothing. Maybe it's overridden in a derived class?

The `(void) someArg;` trick is used to suppress warnings about unused arguments.

Comment: But that class is full of similar functions .. if it doesn't do any thing how do I get sometimes true and other time false? Link to the code from github [Link](https://github.com/gligneul/Scene-Graph/blob/master/Node.cpp)

Comment: @KuMu  Read carefully:  **"Maybe it's overridden in a derived class"**.

Comment: For example, [light nodes](https://github.com/gligneul/Scene-Graph/blob/master/Light.h) [group nodes](https://github.com/gligneul/Scene-Graph/blob/master/Group.h) [camera nodes](https://github.com/gligneul/Scene-Graph/blob/master/Camera.h)

Comment: I was confused by the Visual studio debugger. It never went to the correct part of the sub-classed class. That class is sub-classed and after that these virtual functions are overridden without the keyword "override" which confused med. Never seen this kind of usage before for some reason. Thanks.